# Use clipping to round corners of ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a `RelativeLayout` that needs to have rounded upper left and upper right corners. I can do this with a drawable background defined in XML with corners topLeftRadius and topRightRadius. But... This `RelativeLayout` also need to have a background that is a layer-list with a tiled bitmap and shape combo, and the tiled bitmap does not have a corners parameter in the drawable XML. So my idea was to to make a `RelativeLayout` with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    path.reset();
    rect.set(0, 0, w, h);
    path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    path.close();
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int save = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(save);
}
```

Sadly no clipping is happening, I was expecting it to clip all four corners of my RelativeLayout, but nothing is happening. The "onSizeChanged" and "dispatchDraw" methods are both called, I tested that. I have also tried to turn off hardware acceleration, but it does nothing.

My `RelativeLayout` is part of a larger layout, and that layout is inflated in a subclass of `FrameLayout`, and that subclass is then used a a row in a `RecyclerView`, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Having defined this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <com.playground.RoundedRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Where `RoundedRelativeLayout` has following implementation:

```
    public class RoundedRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

        private RectF rectF;
        private Path path = new Path();
        private float cornerRadius = 15;

        public RoundedRelativeLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public RoundedRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public RoundedRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            rectF = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
            resetPath();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            int save = canvas.save();
            canvas.clipPath(path);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(save);
        }

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int save = canvas.save();
            canvas.clipPath(path);
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(save);
        }

        private void resetPath() {
            path.reset();
            path.addRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
            path.close();
        }
    }
```

You'll get following output:

[image]

<sup>The implementation is shamelessly stolen from [RoundKornerLayouts](https://github.com/JcMinarro/RoundKornerLayouts) project.</sup>

Comment: Ha, I had the exact same code just structured a little differently, but I was missing the draw override. I thought only the dispatchDraw would be called for a ViewGroup, and not the draw.

Comment: Because you are applying a background to the `ViewGroup`, that results in `onDraw()` method of `ViewGroup` to be called, otherwise by default it would **not**, unless explicitly instructed via `setWillNotDraw(false)` API.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a Kotlin version of azizbekian's answer:

```
class RoundedRelativeLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs) {

    private lateinit var rectF: RectF
    private val path = Path()
    private var cornerRadius = 15f

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        rectF = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
        resetPath()
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val save = canvas.save()
        canvas.clipPath(path)
        super.draw(canvas)
        canvas.restoreToCount(save)
    }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val save = canvas.save()
        canvas.clipPath(path)
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
        canvas.restoreToCount(save)
    }

    private fun resetPath() {
        path.reset()
        path.addRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
        path.close()
    }
}
```

#### Edit

As a bonus here's how to add the cornerRadius as an extra xml attribute you can set, just add this to `res/values/styleable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RoundedRelativeLayout">
        <attr name="cornerRadius" format="float"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and then add this init method to the `RoundedRelativeLayout` class:

```
init {
    val ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedRelativeLayout)
    cornerRadius = ta.getFloat(R.styleable.RoundedRelativeLayout_cornerRadius, 15f)
    ta.recycle()
}
```

And now when you use the layout you can set the cornerRadius in the xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" <-- Make sure you include this line
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

    .
    .
    .

    <your.package.name.RoundedRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/roundedRect"
            app:cornerRadius="24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    .
    .
    .
```